# Separate profiles?

Tags: support, profile-page, login

I'm a professional programmer, and very active on StackOverflow.com.

I'm also a private pilot, and starting to get active on Aviation.StackExchange.com.

For both professional and vanity reasons, I want my StackOverflow profile to tout my programming knowledge and experience.   Employers don't really need to know about my flying skills.

Similarly, I'd like my Aviation profile to describe my flying experience.  But I don't think my skills with various CPU architectures are relevant to flying.

But ultimately, I'm one person, so I want one login.

It seems that one login == one profile.  Is that right?
Does StackExchange have any provision (or future plans?) to have different presentation s of the same person?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can log in to every stack exchange site with the same login but setup your profile differently, including your display name. When you save your profile changes just make sure you don't click "Save and Copy to All My Accounts" just the regular save button.

Comment: Doesn't the changed account still remain associated with other, unchanged accounts? For example in the main Stack Exchange profile and "accounts" section of the user profile pages on individual sites?

Comment: Yes, they'll be associated @TildalWave - but the actual content of the profiles can be completely different if the owner wishes (which appears to be the desire expressed here).